# Tag Set Delayed and D

Tags: functions, functional-style

I used the Tag Set Delayed to set

```
F /: D[F[f_], x_] := F[D[f, x]]
```

It works if I give as input a single `F`:

```
D[F[g[x]],x] = F[g'[x]]
```

the result is as expected. However if I insert a linear combination of `F`s

```
D[F[g[x]] + F[h[x]], x] = F'[g[x]]g'[x]+F'[h[x]]h'[x]
```

instead of

```
D[F[g[x]] + F[h[x]], x] = F[g'[x]] + F[h'[x]]
```

I was expecting the last result since I thought that first the `D` would distribute on `F`s

```
D[F[g[x]],x] + D[F[h[x]],x]
```

and then my Tag Set Delayed would have applied.

## Instead

Defining

```
d[a_ + b_] := d[a] + d[b];
F/:d[F[g_],x_]:=F[d[g,x]];
```

I gat the expected result

```
d[F[g[x]]+F[h[x]],x] = F[d[g[x],x]]+F[d[h[x],x]]
```

Which is what I would like to have with `D`.

## Question

How can I get the same behavior with `D`?

Comment: Can you provide a MWE?

Comment: I was thinking `F` as an operator. Imagine `F = Sum`. It is linear and a derivative can be moved inside.

Comment: With `F = Sum` there is no contradiction in `D[Sum[f[x] , ...], x]`. How can I have a similar structure with a generic `F`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn off automatic handling of derivatives for your function by adjusting the system options:

```
With[{old = OptionValue[SystemOptions["DifferentiationOptions"],"DifferentiationOptions"->"ExcludedFunctions"]},
    SetSystemOptions["DifferentiationOptions" -> "ExcludedFunctions" -> DeleteDuplicates[Append[old, F]]]
];

D[F[a_], r__] ^:= F[D[a, r]]
```

Then:

```
D[F[g[x]] + F[h[x]], x]
```

> F[g'[x]] + F[h'[x]]